# c# OdbcDataAdapter returns more rows than LIMIT

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, datatable, odbc

I'm retrieving rows from a PostgreSQL database using an `OdbcConnection` object and an `OdbcDataAdapter`.

The query passed to the OdbcDataAdapter is "`SELECT * FROM schema.table OFFSET 100000 LIMIT 100000`"

The offset and limit are stored in variable because they are used to process rows in batches of 100,000. But at runtime this is their value. When I run this query in SQL, it returns 100,000 rows as expected - using the offset correctly. **However, when `OdbcDataAdapter.Fill(dt)` is called, the row count on the dt is 200,000 - despite a LIMIT of 100,000 being in the query**!!!!

This problem continues as the program iterates with the row count increasing by the offset each time. So when the offset is 300,000, the row count is 400,000. I can't replicate this behaviour in SQL.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: what happens when you run the query directly on database using pgadmin?

Comment: then its definitely something with code code where LIMIT is set. can you copy the code where you are setting the LIMIT and how it is set

Comment: I can't unfortunately as the code is on a prod server, so would mean writing it out, and it's been scrapped for something else now. I'm still leaving this up in interest though.